# C ++ cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone

Tags: c++, overloading, leap-year

I'm new in c++, and I'm writing a program that calculate if the entered year is leap or not, but this returns me an error that says: cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone. And also, doesn't accept the operator "==" with a boolean expression. Why?
Thanks.
This is my code:

```
using namespace std;

int leap_year(int year);


bool div(int num, int divid) {

    if (num % divid == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int leap_year(int year) {
    if (div(year, 400))
        return 365;
    else if (div(year, 100) & div(year, 400) == false)
        return 366;
    else
        return 365;
}

void main() {
    int year;
    cout << "Year: ";
    cin >> year;

    int result = leap_year(year);
    cout << result;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `if (div(year, 100) & div(year, 400) == false)` has a style mistake and a logical error. Change `&` to `&&` to fix the logical error. Change `div(year, 400) == false` to `!div(year, 400)` to fix the style error.

Comment: Also, `main` returns `int`. Your compiler is not doing you any favors by allowing `void`.

Comment: if I use !div(year, 400) I get an error: no operator corresponding to the operands "!". Why?

Comment: Probably because you haven't fixed the overload problem.

Comment: what is the overload problem? I don't know this error and nobody answer me

Answer (score 7):

Your definition of `bool div(int num, int divid)` is shadowing [`std::div`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div), because you pollute your global namespace due to `using namespace std;`

Remove `using namespace std;` and use `std::` where appropriate.

Comment: it does not work yet